# What is the probablity of flipping 1024 fair coins without ever getting 11 of the same side in a row?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So you have a perfect $50/50$ coin, and you flip it $1024$ times... What are the chances you'll be able to do that without ever getting 11 of the same side in a row?

This is probably a dumb question. I've tried searching for this on this site and other sites and haven't found the exact answer I'm looking for. I've found $\frac{1}{1024}$ chance of getting all heads if you flip 10 coins in a row and other similar things but not this.

I'm trying to use the martingale betting system (double your bet on a loss until you win, and then go back to the starting bet) I'm doing this IN A VIDEO GAME. NOT a casino/real world game. There's a mini game inside the actual game which actually has a $50/50$ chance of winning. I have enough right now to cover $11$ losses in a row starting with the min bet. I might be able to get to $12$ or $13$ but $14$ losses in a row is a bit farfetched at least in the short term... not to mention at that point I'd be betting so much just to get the min bet when/if I win. So I'm hoping the chances are pretty good or I could get to a point where they are.

Comment: This seems like a difficult question, actually. I could give you a nasty recursive formula, but getting a closed form out of it would be difficult.

Comment: It is not far away from $\exp\left(-\frac{1024}{2^{11}}\right)=e^{-1/2} \approx 0.61$.

Comment: is there any significance to 1024 in this game?

Comment: The last paragraph is rather depressing. Mathematics should teach you that those "martingales" just don't work. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83904/on-martingale-betting-system

Comment: Mathematics will teach you, not how to win against a (fair) casino, but why you cannot win.

Comment: @leonbloy depends what you mean by "work". martingale won't change the EV of the game but can be used to maximize expected utility - especially in a 0 EV game where all strategies are equally good/bad. OP never claimed he wanted to "beat the casino".

Comment: @Abovestand I think we would need to know more about the player's utility function in order to say whether the proposed strategy has a positive utility. And I'm having a hard time imagining what utility function would make this strategy anywhere near optimal.

Comment: Evan, what is your goal in playing this game-within-the-game? How much "money" do you start with, and what are the benefits/consequences of winning or losing each possible amount? For example, if you start with 1024 and you need 1500 in order to advance to the next part of the larger game, you might decide the utility of 1500 or greater is 1 and the utility of anything less is zero.

Comment: @leonbloy I read that article and others like it and i do agree, in a real world casino game with max bet limits/personal spending limits, people eventually lose everything because it all evens out. But the example you gave uses 5 losses in a row, and ive seen some with 10 that fail too but it of course had lower odds of happening so it was better. So what im doing is just trying to get a basis on the formula because in this video game i actually can get an "infinite" amount of money and play a programmed 50/50 game. I could get to 20+ losses in a row given the time to earn by playing first

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much. As a novice, could you explain to me how your formula works? What does exp and e stand for lol. Id like to be able to find different answers with different data using it but embarrassingly dont know how

Comment: @EvanKaplan  Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: @Abovestand Well 1024 represented the number of bets i would need to win without losing 11 times in a row, in order to double what i currently have. Starting with .5 and doubling until 512. (being down 1023.5 total at that point)                   
But, after posting i realize that I should have worded this differently because i obviously want to do it infinitely rather than just 1024 times so that number is irrelevant and doesnt help. i should have asked for a formula to find out how many times youd have to double in order for the probability to be so minuscule it might just work.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_k(n)$ be the probability of $n$ flips and no $k$ equal successive outcomes. Then
$$f_k(n) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } n = 0;\\
f_k(n - 1) - [n \ge k]\cdot\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot(1 + [n = 1])\cdot f_k(n - k), & \text{if } n > 0;\\
\end{cases}$$
because after new flip can be $k$th equal successive outcomes if $k$ last outcomes are equal and not equal to the one before them if it exists. Computing this value for all $n \le 1024$ and $k = 11$ we get $f_{11}(1024) \approx 0.6076519$ that is really close to $e^{-1/2}$ mentioned by Henry in comments.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps. So .61 in favor of getting 11 of the same side in a row? That's pretty high. :/ I would love to be able to know how to be able to use this formula to keep raising the k = 11 higher and see if it ever reaches a point where its plausible

Comment: @EvanKaplan $0.61$ is approximately the probability of *not* getting a run of $11$ the same in $1024$ flips

Comment: @Henry Thank you, im an idiot. I really appreciate your time answering my questions and the help youve been.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to put this in the simplest terms possible.
I assume that on each "coin toss" in your video-game casino, you decide how much play-money to bet. Lets call the units of play-money *dollars.* If you bet $x$ dollars on a particular coin toss, then with probability $\frac12$ (i.e. $50\%$ of the time) you lose $x$ dollars, and with probability $\frac12$ you gain $x$ dollars.

Each single bet therefore has expectation zero for you:
$\frac12(x) + \frac12(-x) = 0.$ By linearity of expectation, *any* sequence of bets according to *any* strategy (including strategies that change the amounts or number of bets you make depending on what happened on the bets already made) will have expectation zero.
If you start with $n$ dollars, the expected amount of money you will have at the end is $n$ plus the expected amount you win (namely, zero), so the expected value of your bankroll at the end of the strategy is $n.$

So let's suppose you have a strategy to double your money. Starting with $n$ dollars in your bankroll, this strategy is designed to make your bankroll reach $2n$ dollars exactly.
The strategy consists of a set of rules for how much to bet on the first coin toss, and then how much to bet on each subsequent coin toss depending on what your previous wins and losses were.

The strategy is designed so it never bets enough to make your bankroll more than $2n$ if you win the bet.
If you ever reach $2n$ dollars, the strategy ends. (It has reached its goal.)
If you ever reach $0$ dollars, the strategy ends because you cannot play any more. You may or may not want to include a rule in your strategy to stop playing after some sequence of wins and losses even though you have more than $0$ dollars but less than $2n$ dollars at that point.

For example, suppose you started with $1024$ dollars, and at some point during play you have just lost ten bets in a row starting with $1$ dollar and doubling each later bet.
That is, you have lost 
$1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256 + 512 = 1023$ dollars 
in the latest sequence of ten bets.
In order to continue the doubling strategy, you would need to place a bet of $1024$ dollars on the next bet.
But it happens that you had only $1415$ dollars just before this run of losing bets, so after the ten losses you have only $392$ dollars remaining.
Do you quit, or do you continue with a different rule for how much to bet each time?

Depending on what you decide to do in situations like the one I have just described, you come up with a strategy that falls into one of the following two categories:

1. When the strategy ends, you have either $2n$ dollars or $0$ dollars. There is zero probability to end with any other result.
2. The strategy may end with $2n$ dollars, $0$ dollars, or something in between. There is a positive probability of a result greater than $0$ but less than $2n,$ and zero probability of any result less than $0$ or greater than $2n.$

Any strategy of type 1 will have a $\frac12$ chance of ending with $2n$ dollars and a $\frac12$ chance of ending with $0$ dollars.
Due to linearity of expectation, no other distribution of final results is possible. That's because the expected value of your bankroll at the end is
$$
E[\text{ending bankroll}] = p(2n) + (1-p)0 = 2pn,
$$
where $p$ is the probability to end with $2n$ dollars, but by linearity of
expectation, $E[\text{ending bankroll}] = n,$ therefore $2pn = n,$
therefore $p=\frac12.$

A strategy of type 2, however, will have an expected value that looks like this:
$$
E[\text{ending bankroll}] = p_0(2n) + p_1m_1 + p_2m_2 + \cdots + p_km_k
  + (1-p_0 - p_1 - \cdots - p_k)0,
$$
where each $m_i$ is some number of dollars you might end up with,
$0 < m_i < 2n,$ with some positive probability $p_i.$
The term $(1-p_0 - p_1 - \cdots - p_k)0$ is just zero, of course, so we
can drop it.
The sum $p_1m_1 + p_2m_2 + \cdots + p_km_k$ is a positive number;
let $k = p_1m_1 + p_2m_2 + \cdots + p_km_k.$ Then
$$
E[\text{ending bankroll}] = p_0(2n) + k.
$$
Again, by linearity of expectation, $E[\text{ending bankroll}] = n,$ therefore $2p_0n + k = n,$ therefore $2p_0n = n - k,$
therefore $p_0=\frac12 - \frac{k}{2n} < \frac12.$

There you have it. Your choices are between (1) some kind of strategy that doubles your money with probability exactly $\frac12,$
and otherwise makes you go bust,
and (2) some kind of strategy that doubles your money with probability *less than* $\frac12,$
and otherwise either makes you go bust or leaves you with some intermediate result.

The second kind of strategy does not seem to be what you want.
In any case, any possible gains it might make will be balanced by the 
possible losses it might cause in the end.

Assuming you want a type 1 strategy, my recommendation is this:
go to the casino and bet your entire bankroll on the first bet.
You will either double your money or go broke, a fifty-fifty chance of either, which is the same odds that *any other* type 1 strategy will
give you, but it is much simpler than any other strategy and wastes
less of your time playing.